# compare only xml tags in linux

Tags: xml, linux, shell

need help to compare xml tags
I need to compare 2 xml file tags in Linux environment.
i just want to compare only the tags not the value.
 say for eg:

1.xml has

```
<CSVPrefix> 01 </CSVPrefix>
<CSVPostfix> e </CSVPostfix>
<CSVLandingZone> xyz </CSVLandingZone>
```

2.xml has

```
 <CSVPostfix>te</CSVPostfix>
 <CSVLandinone>/tmp/csv/</CSVLandingZone>
```

Is there any free tool available to do this ?
or even a piece of shell script is fine as that is what is supported in our setup.

NO other language is supported currently, hence i cannot write any py or java code to compare this.

Comment: You could probably kluge something together out of sed and awk and sort and other unix/linux command-line tools... but there's nothing that ships with Linux which will do what you want without that effort. (If you could download a free tool, why can't you download a programming language or XSLT processor or something else suitable for the task?)

Comment: Yeah very true. But the free tool is more for my personal verification to speed up the process. I have been asked to keep the code very simple using shell so that the end user can modify it if needed. Just following what has been asked to do.

Comment: you can use xslt processor ... depending on the version of Linux there may be perl installed if that's the case you can use perl(1) to do this quite easily

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 (any shell):

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/some-root/*" -v "name()" -n file1.xml
CSVPrefix
CSVPostfix
CSVLandingZone
```

Step 2 (something bash-like):

```
diff ... <(xmlstarlet sel ...) <(xmlstarlet sel ...)
```